# Stacking Switching

Tags: cisco-catalyst

We do have 9 switches in stack , after IOS upgradation only on switch came up but remaining switches are down , can you please help me how to troubleshoot this problem ?

Comment: Please tell us how exactly you upgraded them and what model of switch this is

Comment: this question is asked in interview